# WSDL is changed after publishing

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb, wsdl

When I publish a web service created from a WSDL, the WSDL which is created after publishing is different than the original one. The difference is that WSDL/XSD created after publishing had additional element(ARG0) which wraps all root elements.

Because of the reason above, I could not share original WSDL/XSD to client developers since original WSDL and the one created after publishing is not same.

I am using Java as a programming language and JAX-WS.

using API javax.xml.ws.Endpoint to publish the web service without needing any Application server.

Endpoint.publish(url,webserviceinstance)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the problem is unneccesary wrapping issue, I focused on wrapping annotations. Eventually I have found out that there is a related annotation for this issue. After adding following annotation statement at the beginning of Class ,problem has been solved.

```
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle=SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
public class WebServiceHandler implements WebService {
//....
}
```

From now on, I can make succesfull request created from original WSDL to deployed machine.

Answer (score 0):

If you post the wsdl, a better assessment can be made.  Given that you are seeing an unexpected wrapper, my guess is that jax-ws is interpreting your original wsdl differently than you intend.  The page here (http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-whichwsdl/) discusses different wsdl configurations.  My suggestion is that you follow the instructions for using the document/literal/wrapped convention as it is more or less in the mainstream for soap-based services.

The resulting published wsdl will still likely be a little different in terms of service name, port name or namespace unless you use the @Webservice annotation attributes to force these to particular values, but they will be consistent such that you can provide the published wsdl to your clients and expect success.

Comment: Why wsdl is not changed when I deploy a webservice to an Application Server? It  indicates that there should not be wrong with wsdl description but javax.xml.ws.Endpoint API.

Comment: Without the generated-from wsdl I am only speculating, but it sounds like jax-ws is enforcing a convention that you do not expect.  Code generation tools (wsimport) and jax-ws make some decisions based on wsdl construction.  The different wsdl styles are explained in the page at the ibm.com link.

Comment: wsimport tool does not change the convention while creating code from wsdl. I though EndPoint class make some decision in terms of wrapping request and response parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The most common reason for this type of issue is that the class implementing the Web service doesn't have an `@WebService` annotation with the correct `endpointInterface` attribute. In fact, it is not sufficient to implement the endpoint interface generated from the WSDL.